# limit of indeterminate of type

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to0}(1-x)^\frac{1}{x}$$

I know we have to use logarithms to evaluate the limit, but isn't it the type of $1^{\infty }$? so the answer should be prety straightforward as $1^{\infty }$ which is 1, but actually the answer is $e^{-7}$

Comment: What makes you think ``$1^\infty$'' should be $1$?

Comment: @Zhanxiong  isn't $1^{\infty }$ is like $1^{any number you can image }$ is always 1? for example, $1^{10000000 }$=1

Comment: it will never be 1^ infinity. x tends to zero, but never reaches zero. you cant just plug x = zero. it will be a number little less than 1, multiplied many number of times. it will be a positive number less than 1.

Comment: The symbol $\infty$ is essentially different from any ***finite*** number, no matter how big it is. I think your teacher should point out that to you. Also, you cannot treat $1 - o(1)$ as $1$, especially when it serves as base of some exponential functions.

Comment: For many this is one of the standard limits $\lim_{x \to 0}(1 + ax)^{1/x} = e^{a}$. Here $a = 1$ so the answer is $e^{-1} = 1/e$. Otherwise you can take logs and use the standard limit $\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\log(1 - x)}{x} = -1$ and again get the same answer $1/e$. You have typo in question which says the answer is $e^{-7}$.

Comment: Please avoid using arguments involving expressions like $1^{\infty}$ because such expressions have no meaning apart from indicating a type of indeterminate form. And there are ways to deal with indeterminate form like $1^{\infty}$ by taking logs but the expression $1^{\infty}$ by itself does not mean anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what you mean. To use the following proposition of limits:
$$\lim f=a,\lim g=b,then  \; \lim f^g=a^b $$
you have to make sure that $0\ne a,b$ should be real number, not $\infty$

So your claim:$1^{\infty}=1$ is not right

Comment: but isn't $1^{any number}=1$?for example, $1^{100}=1$,$1^{1000000000000}=1$

Comment: That's right, we only need the limit of $\lim g$ a finite number in $\lim  f^g=a^b$, no matter how large $b$ is.

Comment: @whoisit When you deal with complex numbers, $1^{\text{something}}$ may not be $1$ anymore. So it is best to avoid such arguments.

Answer (score 1):

For sufficiently small nonzero $x$, the quantity $(1 - x)^{1/x}$ is always positive, hence it may be rewritten as
\begin{align}
\exp(\log (1 - x)^{1/x}) = \exp\left(\frac{1}{x}\log(1 - x)\right)
\end{align}

Now you can evaluate the exponent part by L'Hospital rule (it is of type $0/0$):
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\log(1 - x)}{x} = -\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{1 - x} = -1.$$
Hence the original limit is $e^{-1}$, by the continuity of function $x \mapsto e^x$.

Answer (score 0):

You also could have used Taylor series $$y=(1-x)^\frac{1}{x}\implies \log(y)=\frac{1}{x}\,\log(1-x)$$ Now, Taylor series $$\log(y)=\frac{1}{x}\,\left( -x-\frac{x^2}{2}+O\left(x^3\right)\right)=-1-\frac{x}{2}+O\left(x^2\right)$$ When $x \to 0$, then $\log(y)\to -1$ and $y\to \frac 1e$.

Notice that you obtain the limit and also how it is approached since, using $y=e^{\log(y)}$ and Taylor again $$y=\frac{1}{e}-\frac{x}{2 e}+O\left(x^2\right)$$